# Create new mount point(/backup) from existing partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, backup, mount

i have 2 partition on cenos 6.4 in SOFT RAID 1.

my current mounted partitions(df -h):

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mountedon
/dev/md1               20G  5.4G   14G  29% /
/dev/md2              897G  680M  851G   1% /home
```

How to mount `/backup` in `/dev/md2` ?
**or**

How to create new mount point for `/backup`?

Comment: What's `backup`? Is it another partition? Partitions are mounted **at** directories, not the other way around. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do. Are you trying to create a new partition in `/dev/md2` and mount that as `backup`?

Comment: What you could also do is backup /home's content, remove/shrink the partition and create new ones as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to make a Bind mount, which will "link" the two directories together.

Extract from `mount` man page :

```
 Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount part of the file  hierarchy
 somewhere else. The call is
      mount --bind olddir newdir
 After this call the same contents is accessible in two places.
```

So do something like :

```
mount --bind /home/backup/ /backup/
```

All you have to do next is to make this permanent by adding the corresponding line to `/etc/fstab`

Comment: i'll take syn backup `/home` to `/backup`. any problem?

Comment: Then you'll have `/home` subdirectories in `/backup` also =)

Answer (score 0):

You may just want a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):

1. Make a directory `/home/backup`
2. Make a symlink from `/backup` to `/home/backup`, i.e. `ln -s /home/backup/ /backup`

Now you can move files to/from `/backup` and they will get stored on `/dev/md2`